# Lexical error while importing JSON data from DATA API in R

Tags: json, r, httr, jsonlite

I am using R, version 3.3.1. I'm trying to import JSON data from DATA API.

Here is my code:

```
req <- list()
my_get <- for (i in 1:length(oib)) {
  reqOP <- rbind(fromJSON(toJSON(content(GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/v1/eoglasna/",
                                             add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "xxxxxxxx"),
                                             query = list(oib = oibreq[i])), type = "application/json"), null = "null", encoding = "UTF-8"), flatten = TRUE))
  req[[i]] <- reqOP
}
json <- do.call(rbind, req)
```

Usualy, this chunk of code works properly any time I retrieve data from this DATA API.

But this time it gives me an error:

```
 Error: lexical error: invalid character inside string.
          tpravka-ovlaĹˇteni sluĹľbenik:Ivana RogiÄ‡"],"tag":["rjeĹˇe
                     (right here) ------^
```

There is a one variable that include large text files. Maybe, this file contains many `"`  and `'` and this makes command `toJSON` impossible to recognize JSON file?